# performance issue with WCF data services

Tags: performance, wcf-data-services

I am new to WCF data services. I have created one sample POC on WCF data service using ADO .NET Entity framework.

When i test Data service by a test project by adding WCF data service as a service reference, a simple select statement for 1000 rows, it took around 25 sec.
Out of 25 sec it took only 5 sec for querying data from DB (Got this info after profiling database).

its weird that WCF data service took around 20 sec for just translation and transport.

Any idea why its taking so much time for translation and transport?

Comment: We'll need more detail to make any forward progress on this question - as you can see, these URL returns 500 entities and returns in <10 seconds: http://odata.netflix.com/Catalog/Titles and http://odata.netflix.com/Catalog/Titles?$format=json. The biggest determining factor should be size on wire. Those payloads were a couple of megs in size. Could you give us some more details?

Comment: I am using eager loading to get navigation properties upfront. so the total size on wire is around 105MB.so, is this 105MB playing role in adding 20 sec overhead or is there any other reason that could cause this as i am using same machine for Hosting service and test client, would payload size add such huge impact in this case?

Comment: That's quite likely the issue - 105MB is HUGE on the wire. You should only eager load things that are actually going to display on the same screen. Is that the case here? Do you really need all 1000 records with expanded data? Can you tell us more about your use case?

Comment: @MarkStafford-MSFT - Yes, I am not going to use the whole set of data on UI. So LazyLoading for List of entities and eagerLoading for a particular entity improves performance a lot. Thanks for your valuable comment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is simply too big.

It is absolutely normal that transport over the network is several times slower than fetching the data from a database, at least when the query consists of more bulk fetching than of complex narrow filtering, and in absence of major performance issues on the database side.

100 MB in 20 seconds = 40 Mbps which would be quite close to hardware limits on 100 Mbps Ethernet given that ~100 MB is just the payload.